# Sorting Lists with numerals

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

If I have a list that all strings but with numerals :

```
a = ['0.01um', 'Control', '0.1um', '0.05um']
```

If I sort the list it looks like this

```
a.sort()
print(a)
['0.01um', '0.05um', '0.1um', 'Control']
```

How can I make it sort with so the strings starting with letters come before the strings starting with numbers, but the numbers are still ordered from smallest to biggest.  For instance :

```
['Control', '0.01um', '0.05um', '0.1um']
```

Comment: How complex can your numbers be?  Could they be in exponential notation?  Do any of your strings  have a `+` or `-`?

Comment: Even more simply: can any of them be >=10? (If they're all simple ASCII digits, no signs, no exponential notation, always one digit on the left of the `.`, then lexicographical sorting is already going to put them in the right order, so you don't need to do anything fancy at all… But if you have to do any fanciness, you might as well go whole-hog and use `natsort` rather than trying to guess how much of the wheel you need to reimplement…)

Comment: Not complex.  No exponential notation.  No negative values. Generally decimal and whole numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, to get your strings starting with letters to collate before those starting with numerics sounds like you'd need to separate them, sort each, then append the one (sub)list to the the other.

To get "natural" sorting of strings containing numerics I'd look at [natsort](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort).

So the code might look something like:

```
#!python
# UNTESTED
import string
from natsort import natsorted
a = ['0.01um', 'Control', '0.1um', '0.05um']
astrs = [x for x in a if not x[0] in string.digits]
anums = [x for x in a if x[0] in string.digits]
results = natsorted(astrs) + natsorted(anums)
```

Comment: Does `natsort` have an option to treat no number part as bigger than any number part instead of smaller? If so, that would reduce this whole thing to a one-liner. If not, this is probably as simple as you can get it.

Comment: I don't know all the features and wrinkles of `natsort` ... I just remember having found it for trivial use cases a long time ago ... things like sorting long lists of IP addresses).

Dig through the sources if you want to see if they can do that for you.

Comment: Well, the OP can dig through it. :) I've used `natsort` exactly once, to port some PyObjC code to portable pure-Python, and its defaults were close enough to Cocoa's defaults that all my unit tests passed, so that's as far as I looked. I just remember that it has a whole bunch of fancy-looking options, and thought it might have one to make this even easier.

Comment: Skimming the documentation, it looks like there is—and you should use that in combination `natsort`s ability to generate a key function. Making it one comprehension will also avoid the overhead of generating two lists and then concatenating them.

Comment: From playing around with `natsort` a bit, it looks like it'll sort strings that don't match to the end by default. You can replace the last three lines with `results = sorted(a, key=natsort.natsort_keygen(alg=natsort.ns.FLOAT))`.

Comment: Very interesting ... is there a way to use this method to sort a pandas dataframe on an index with the values in a?  In my code a = list(df.index.levels[0])

Comment: @BlacklightShining  Maybe I'm missing something but when I use `results = sorted(a, key=natsort.natsort_keygen(alg=natsort.ns.FLOAT))` in place of the last three lines I get `['0.01um', '0.05um', '0.1um', '100um', 'Control']`

Comment: @agf1997 You're absolutely right…I'm trying to find a way to fix that in `natsort`—without resorting to `lambda` and checking the first character by hand again.

Comment: @BlacklightShining and if you have any thoughts to applying this to a pandas data frame per my previous comment I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a key function that “decorates” strings starting with letters with a value lower than strings starting with numbers. For example:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def get_numeric_prefix(str_):
    return float(takewhile(char.isnumeric() or char == '.'))

def letters_before_numbers(str_):
    if not str_:
        return (3, str_)
    elif str_[0].isalpha():
        return (0, str_)
    elif str_[0].isnumeric():
        return (1, get_numeric_prefix(str_))
    else:
        return (2, str_)

a.sort(key=letters_before_numbers)
```

The initial `not str_` case is necessary, because the conditions in the later cases access item `0`, which would raise an `IndexError` if the string were empty. I've elected not to handle strings like `'40.0.3um'` (where there's a prefix that's all numbers and dots, but it's not a properly-formatted `float`)—those will cause the `float()` call to raise a `ValueError`. If you need those to be handled, you should probably [grab a copy of `natsort`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) and [use Jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572986/1561811).

Tuples are compared lexicographically, so `sort()` looks at the number first—if it's lower, the original string will get sorted earlier in the list. This means that you can play with the numbers that are the first elements of the return values to get different kinds of strings to sort earlier or later than others. In this case, strings starting with letters will get sorted first, followed by strings starting with numbers (sorted by the numbers), then strings starting with neither, and finally empty strings.

Comment: This skips the hard part: making the numbers ordered from smallest to biggest, instead of lexicographically. If all of the numbers happen to be <10, this sort of works by coincidence, but unless you know that's a guarantee for the input data, I don't think you want to rely on that.

Comment: Whoops. I think all of us missed that bit.

Comment: [Jim Dennis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29572986/908494); he got it. (The only reason I got it was asking myself "why does he want `natsort`?" and then re-reading the question. :)

Comment: -1 (yes, I'm downvoting my own answer): This isn't nearly as robust as I'd like, and I don't like the way the numbers are parsed out of the strings. Maybe such a key definition would be appropriate in another context, but not here. **Prefer [Jim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29572986/1561811) for properly sorting strings by the numbers they start with.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick involving python's tuple sorting semantics; strings which do not begin with a number will be sorted lexically before all numbers which will be sorted numerically:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: def parse_number(s):
    try:
        m = re.match(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)
        return m and float(m.group(0))
    except:
        pass

In [3]: a = ['0.01um', 'Control', '0.1um', '0.05um']

In [4]: b = sorted((parse_number(i), i) for i in a)

In [5]: [i for _, i in b]
Out[5]: ['Control', '0.01um', '0.05um', '0.1um']
```

Answer (score -1):

In code

```
a = ['0.01um', 'Control', '0.1um', '0.05um']
b = [x for x in a if x and x[0].isdigit()]
c = [x for x in a if x not in b]
d = sorted([(x, float(''.join([y for y in x if y.isdigit() or y == '.']))) for x in b], key=lambda x: x[1])
print sorted(c) + [k for k, v in d]
```

Comment: -1: Not only will this break on empty strings, it will sort the numbers lexicographically _and_ generate two lists, only to concatenate them. It solves _none_ of the problems the other answers do, and only works as a proper answer given the simplest of inputs.